# Dropdown selected value effects other Dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, couch-cms

I am wanting to have a set of interdependent fields of type:
1. Select
2. Select
3. Disabled Textbox

1. Select: should be populated with Student Names (from CMS, that I am
   using).
2. Select: should be populated with Month Name (Jan, Feb, ...,
   Dec).
3. Disabled Textbox: should be populated with a fees amount
   relating to the month selected in #2.

The issue is I am using [AdminBSB](https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/) which has a few design parameters that the CMS that I am using does not allow to use. I am using [CouchCMS](https://www.couchcms.com/).

Can a custom code be created that does not involve data-* attributes? Just using the id attribute and jQuery/javascript.

I am looking for something like:

```
<select name='student_name'>
    <option>Student 1</option>
    <option>Student 2</option>
</select>
<select name='month'>
    <option>Jan</option>
    <option>Feb</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>Dec</option>
</select>
<input name='fees' type='text' readonly />
```

[jsFiddle](https://codepen.io/genxcoders/pen/LBBqRY): to explain what is to be achieved

Now when Student 1 is selected Month dropdown should activate and when a month is selected its corresponding fees should be displayed in the textbox. Data population is not what I am looking for. I just look forward for a working design to start with.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add code into snippet, So anyone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: @jaydeeppatel Bro I do not have a snippet of what I am looking for. But as a reference https://bluelpggas.com/dealer-form.php can be seen. In the "Application Form For" Section there are 3 Selects.

Comment: https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/Bemst is also similar to what I am trying to achieve. But in place of the third Select I need a text box (disabled) whose value shall be submit-able.